# Rust error propagation with distinct type across propagation levels

Tags: rust

What is the recommended way of propagating different error types in Rust (especialy when their definition doesn't merge)?

## The Scenario

Initially, I was curious about how to stop a running thread in Rust. Search suggests it goes through channel communication + conditional.

So, I came up with this code which (1) should loop 5 iterations, (2) with 500 ms sleep in-between iterations, and (3) will stop right after the third iteration.

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::SendError;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Any + Send>> {
    fn some_condition(i: i32) -> bool { 3 == i }

    thread::spawn(|| -> Result<(), SendError<bool>> {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<bool>();

        for i in 0..5 {
            if some_condition(i) { tx.send(true)? }
            if let Ok(true) = rx.try_recv() { break }

            println!("i = {}", i);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
        }

        Ok(())
    }).join()?; // Result<(), SendError<bool>>
                // I get away with a warning: which the expected compiler behaviour
    Ok(())
}
```

## The Problem

While this code run with the expected behaviour, I have a warning for not using the result resulting from the `?` error propagation.

So I was tempted to do `??` instead of just <del>`?`</del>. But then, I got the following compiler warning **error**:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `Box<dyn Any + Send>`
  --> src/main.rs:44:53
   |
27 | fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Any + Send>> {
   |              ------------------------------- expected `Box<dyn Any + Send>` because of this
...
44 |     }).join()/*.map_err(|error| Reference(error))*/??;
   |                                                     ^ the trait `From<SendError<bool>>` is not implemented for `Box<dyn Any + Send>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'a)> as From<E>>
             <Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> as From<&str>>
             <Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> as From<Cow<'a, str>>>
             <Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> as From<String>>
           and 22 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, SendError<bool>>>` for `Result<(), Box<dyn Any + Send>>`
```

Then I realised it is because `Box<dyn Any + Send>` and `From<SendError<bool>>` are not overlapping types... And, the first propagation match the former type and the second, the latter.

So I suspect from here that the problem could be phrased as: [H]ow to define overlapping types for such use cases?

## Envisioned Solution

Intuitively, I tried adding this code that fails (as expected):

```rust
// Only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types [E0117]
impl From<SendError<bool>> for Box<dyn Any + Send> {
    fn from(_: SendError<bool>) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

However, wrapping errors under the same type solves the issue.

Adding:

```rust
use crate::Error::{Reference, Source};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Error {
    Reference(Box<dyn Any + Send>),
    Source(SendError<bool>)
}

impl From<Error> for SendError<bool> {
    fn from(_: Error) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl From<SendError<bool>> for Error {
    fn from(_: SendError<bool>) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Then, changing lines to match

```rust
// ...
                tx.send(true).map_err(|error| Source(error))?;
// ...
    }).join().map_err(|error| Reference(error))??;
```

## Bottom Line

It works but is so verbose that I's like it for Rust to have another way (something in the likes of `Infallible`, maybe).

What is the recommended way of propagating different error types in Rust (especialy when their definition doesn't merge)?

Comment: Please do not post text as images.

Comment: Well noted. And sorry. I'll edit when I get on keyboard later today. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way depends on whether you're writing a library or an application.

For applications, you usually use some `dyn Trait` as you just need to display the error.

Usually you don't use `dyn Any` for errors in Rust but [`dyn std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/trait.Error.html) which is a trait for... well, errors. It contains things like (optional, unstable currently) backtrace, error chain and description via `Display`. Or sometimes you use a crate like [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow), which is basically a better wrapper for `std::error::Error`.

The problem is that `join()` returns [`std::thread::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/thread/type.Result.html) that has an error type `Box<dyn Any + Send>`. This is because it does not represent "just" error, but a panic (that possibly occurred in the spawned thread) - and panic payload is always `Box<dyn Error + Send>`. Usually you just `unwrap()` this to propagate the panic to the spawning thread, but if you want to convert it to a `dyn Error`, you cannot since there's no way to convert `dyn Any` to `dyn Error`.

The way I would tackle this is by creating a wrapper, `PanicError`, that wraps `Box<dyn Error>` and implements `std::error::Error`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct PanicError {
    pub payload: Box<dyn Any + Send>,
}

impl From<Box<dyn Any + Send>> for PanicError {
    fn from(payload: Box<dyn Any + Send>) -> Self {
        Self { payload }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for PanicError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let msg = match self.payload.downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
            Some(&msg) => msg,
            None => match self.payload.downcast_ref::<String>() {
                Some(msg) => msg,
                None => "Box<dyn Any>",
            },
        };
        f.pad(msg)
    }
}

impl Error for PanicError {}
```

Then you can use it like:

```rust
    .join()
    .map_err(PanicError::from)??;
```

For libraries, you want to give maximum flexibility to the consumers. They should be able to print the error, but also to `match` the specific type of error occurred. The usual way to do that is by creating an enum with variant for each possible error, a `From` implementation from each internal error to its variant (so you can use `?` to propagate errors), and `Display` and `Error` implementations. You don't need to write this by hand: there are crates such as  `thiserror` that will help you. I would still use the `PanicError` wrapper, though, as it is easier to work with:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("a thread panicked: {0}")]
    Panic(
        #[source]
        #[from]
        PanicError,
    ),
    #[error("failed to send close signal")]
    CloseSignalSendingFailure(
        #[source]
        #[from]
        SendError<bool>,
    ),
}

fn main() -> Result<(), MyError> { ... }
```

Comment: This' a clear cut. Thank you, Sir.